# How to compute a weighted AUC?

Tags: r, machine-learning, auc, weighted-data

Say that I have a set of training examples with binary 0-1 labels, and corresponding regression labels ranging from 0 to 1.  Normally, to compute AUC I've used the [ROCR package](https://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/) in R, which also allows me to compute the optimal cutoff point.  In addition to these labels and predictions, I also have a weight column which ranges from 0 to 1 and signifies the importance of each example.  I was wondering how I could compute the AUC and optimal cutoff point of these examples, taking these weights into account.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question is still valid, but you can use [PRROC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PRROC/index.html) package in R for weighted AUC computations.

Comment: glmnet package also has it